# How can i solve invalid regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal

This is error patch:

[image]

And here is my code for hide modal in iphone device

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var modal = $('.myModal', window.top.document); // Works
    modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var width = $(window).width(); 
      var testdevice =  /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
      if(testdevice) {
        $(this).modal('toggle');
      }
    });
  });
```

Comment: Hi.. What you are trying to do using this regular expression

Comment: I want to hide modal in iphone device. @Shibon

Comment: hi please see this link they have done 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3514784/what-is-the-best-way-to-detect-a-mobile-device-in-jquery

Comment: Have you got the solution from the above link ??

Comment: Wait i will try. @Shibon

Comment: Sorry @Shibon this isn't working same error for this.

Comment: can you show the code which you have tried from that thread

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
    var modal = $('.myModal', window.top.document); // Works
    modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
      var width = $(window).width(); 
      var testdevice =  /iPhone/i.test(navigator.userAgent);
     if(testdevice) {
        $(this).modal('toggle');
      }
    });
  });

Comment: This is my code @Shibon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var modal = $('.myModal', window.top.document); // Works
modal.on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
  var width = $(window).width(); 
  if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
    $(this).modal('toggle');
  }
});
});
```